# Is it possible to have fxnotes in caption of figure or table?

Tags: floats, fixme

I am using the fixme package with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, draft]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fixme}
\fxsetup{layout=footnote}
\begin{document}
Fixme notes work\fxnote{Test} in the text.

\begin{table}
\caption{But not in the caption \fxnote{Not here!}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Now I would like to have fxnote scattered around the text, but I have a problem with fxnote that belong to a figure or the caption of a figure.

Preferably I would like to be able to quickly write a fxnote next to a word in a figure and then be able to return to it later.

Are there any best practices for this?
Just placing the \fxnote{} in the caption will display a small superscript number but the contents of the note are not displayed anywhere.

EDIT: It turns out that using the Memoir package changes the behavior with respect to e.g. article class.
In Memoir (with \fxsetup{layout=footnote}) it fails silently.
In Memoir (without \fxsetup{layout=footnote}) it fails with "Float(s) lost."
In article (with/without \fxsetup{layout=footnote}) the fxnote is displayed in the caption.

The question then becomes:
Is that a bug in Memoir? I prefer the article class handling, as it will actually display the fxnote. Is there a way to get Memoir to behave like the article class?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\fxnote` uses insertions and insertions can't be nested.

Comment: @egreg Is it a bug then, that it does not give a warning or error in Memoir?

Comment: @HansHarhoff If you change `\fxnote` into `\protect\footnote`, then you get no footnote and no warning either.

Answer (score 3):

Section 3.5.5 of the manual:

> This section describes some other common problems that people have encountered using FiXme. Although FiXme might not be directly responsible for them, it is still good to keep them in mind.
>
> **Footnotes and margin paragraphs in floats** Using footnotes in figures (and a fortiori in a figure’s caption) does not work in general. Although there are some workarounds out there (for instance, using `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` directly), there is no completely reliable solution and it is not possible to detect that situation automatically.

So, no: `\fxnote` doesn't work in `\caption` and it's documented.

Answer (score 2):

Since (per egreg's answer) the fxnotes do not work as marginpars and footnotes if placed in a caption, I have found a workaround to have a useful fxnote anyway.

In article class the \fxnote command will generate an inline fixme note if placed in a caption.

In Memoir this does not work. Instead you can use the inline option:

```
\caption{But not in the caption \fxnote[inline]{Not here!}}
```

to trigger this behavior.
I am not sure if it is a bug or a feature that article and memoir handle this differently.

Finally, for the lazy, here is a command that you can put in your preamble to define fxinline to make an inline fxnote even if the default is set differently.
\newcommand{\fxinline}[1]{\fxnote[inline]{#1}}

Here is the full example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, draft]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fixme}
\fxsetup{layout=footnote}
\newcommand{\fxinline}[1]{\fxnote[inline]{#1}}

\begin{document}
Fixme notes work\fxnote{Test} in the main text.

\begin{table}
\caption{But not in the caption \fxinline{Unless you use inline!}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```