# How can I get a margin fxnote next to a footnote?

Tags: footnotes

I would like to have a margin fxnote that refers to a footnote.

I've read it is not possible for captions in figures and tables: [Is it possible to have fxnotes in caption of figure or table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256283/is-it-possible-to-have-fxnotes-in-caption-of-figure-or-table), is it the same for footnotes?

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[draft,silent,margin,author=Note]{fixme}
\fxsetup{theme=color,marginface=\singlespacing\footnotesize}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{3cm}\reversemarginpar 

\begin{document}

This is the kind of fxnote I like for normal text.\fxnote{My note.}
I would like to have a fxnote in a footnote, something like this:\footnote{This\fxnote{This is a fxnote in the footnote.} is a footnote.} (but of course it doesn't work).

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried the marginnote layout and disabling innerlayout, something like that is my normal setup. One downside though, multiple notes may overlap in the margin, upside marginnote works almost everywhere

Comment: @daleif Steven B. Segletes has already given an answer that is good for me, but, if you have time, could you post an example of your solution? I would like to see which one is better but I'm not so skilled to implement your suggestion by myself, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested, here is a purely `fixme` solution. As mentioned using the `marginnote` layout, notes can be added almost everywhere. I've added the `innerlayout=noinline`, then margin notes also works inside floats (where it would normally be using inline).

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[draft]{fixme}
\fxsetup{
  layout=marginnote,
  marginface=\tiny,
 inlineface=,
 innerlayout=noinline,% not really relevant in this example, but nice to have
}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{3cm}

\begin{document}

This is the kind of fxnote I like for normal text.\fxnote{My note.}
I would like to have a fxnote in a footnote, something like this:%
\footnote{This \fxnote{This is a fxnote in the footnote.} is a footnote.} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! I prefer this solution, it is simple and allows to use draft/final option of fixme package, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could fake it, as I do below with a concocted `\Fxnote`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[draft,silent,margin,author=Note]{fixme}
\fxsetup{theme=color,marginface=\singlespacing\footnotesize}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{3cm}\reversemarginpar 
\usepackage{tabto,xcolor}
\newcommand\Fxnote[1]{\tabto*{-\marginparwidth}\smash{\raisebox{\baselineskip}{%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\marginparwidth-7pt}{\raggedleft%
  \color{green!50!black}\singlespacing\footnotesize Note: #1}}}\tabto*{\TabPrevPos}}

\begin{document}

This is the kind of fxnote I like for normal text.\fxnote{My note.}
I would like to have a fxnote in a footnote, something like this:%
\footnote{This \Fxnote{This is a fxnote in the footnote.} is a footnote.} 
(but of course it doesn't work).

Here is my own Fxnote\Fxnote{My note.}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is it possible to modify your command like this: _if mode=draft then execute your command else excute a dummy command that does nothing_ ?

Comment: Disregard my previous request, daleif has already posted a solution that exactly sastisfies my desiderata, thank you.